# Is Doctype part of the Stack Exchange family?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange, doctype

I can't tell from the site design whether [Doctype](http://doctype.com/) is created by the same team as Stack Overflow.

It doesn't seem to be, as it doesn't have support for OpenID like the other sites (i.e. Server Fault and Super User).

So, is Doctype part of the same family of sites as Stack Overflow?

If not, is there a similar site for web designers created by the Stack Overflow guys that gets the same kind of traffic?

Comment: I just tried to modernize this, but right after I finished I noticed  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85675/what-is-the-status-of-html-css-layout-questions-on-so. Maybe this question is no longer needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**Editor's note:** This is no longer functioning. What was behind this website is discussed in this blogpost linked below]

Doctype supports OpenID! See https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/08/stack-overflow-and-doctype/.