# Is DocType owned by Stack Overflow Internet Services Inc.?

Tags: discussion, doctype

DocType seems to be a little different than the rest of the Stack Exchange sites, old and new.  There are various references to a 'Litmus', but it's not quite clear what the relationship is between the Stack Exchange network and DocType.

From the DocType FAQ:

> Who built Doctype?
>
> Doctype was built by the people who
>   run Litmus...

Does this mean that these 'Litmus' people are running a franchise of sorts for the stack exchange system?

Or is DocType wholly owned and run by Stack Overflow Internet Services Inc.?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is doctype part of the StackOverflow family?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61295/is-doctype-part-of-the-stackoverflow-family)

Comment: I just tried to modernize the question I linked in my possible dupe comment, but right after I finished, I noticed  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85675/what-is-the-status-of-html-css-layout-questions-on-so. Maybe neither of these questions is needed anymore...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't owned or run by Stack Overflow Internet Services. It belongs to Litmux and is run by them.

See the blog post [*Stack Overflow and Doctype*](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/08/stack-overflow-and-doctype/) where Jeff explains the situation of them being *inspired* by Stack Overflow.